# How to generate UTC datetimeoffset in SSIS derived column transformation?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using derived column transformation in SSIS dataflow. The datatype for CreatedDate and LastModifiedDate in derived column transformation is DT_DBTIMESTAMP

[image: SSIS Derived column transformation]

The GETUTCDATE() function in derived column transformation is generating the UTC datetime but without +00:00 offset. When it inserts into SQL Server database, it is appending my local timezone which is +05:30.

I want SSIS to append +00:00 timezone instead of +05:30. It is correctly generating the UTC datetime with the GETUTCDATE(), but timezone is incorrect. I tried using SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() in derived column transformation, but it doesn't allow.

[image: SQL Server table]

Comment: It got solved by added (DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET,7)GETUTCDATE() as expression in derived column transformation and selecting the datatype of those columns as DT_DBDATETIMEOFFSET.

Answer (score 0):

`GETUTCDATE()` is the wrong default value. That returns a `datetime` value in UTC, but does not include any timezone info, so the server is adjusting it to its local time when you insert it into a `datetimeoffset` column. This is a database issue, not SSIS.

Instead use `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` which has timezone information, and is also more accurate. To adjust it to UTC, use `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`

```sql
ALTER TABLE YourTable
DROP CONSTRAINT YourDefaultConstraint;

ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT YourDefaultConstraint DEFAULT
  ( SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' )
  FOR CreatedDate;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/BX-rwEqi)

Comment: I cannot use SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() in SSIS dataflow. Moreover, I cannot change the table structure to include DEFAULT at the moment.

Comment: Well that's the real answer, you need to change the `DEFAULT` constraint